# Strange behavior from enumerate()

Tags: python, python-2.7, enumerate

So I'm reading in this PPM file, reading it line-by-line, manipulating it here and there, and writing it out new lines to another file.  I tried producing a minimal working example to reproduce the behavior, but when I write a minimal example the strange behavior goes away--but I can't figure out what part of this is causing the strange behavior.  So the full code is below.

```
def flip_horizontal(infile, outfile):
with open(os.getcwd() + '\\' + infile, 'r') as f:
    outfile = open(os.getcwd() + '\\' + outfile, 'w')
    rgbCounter = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i < 3:
            outfile.write(line)
        if i == 1:
            width = int(line.split()[1])
            lineList = [None for i in range(width*3)]
            if width > 1024:
                print "Image size too large:  Buffer can only store 1024 \
                    pixels at a time.  Aborting negate_red."
                break
        if i > 2:
            print line
            for integer in line.split():
                if rgbCounter%3 == 0:
                    lineList[width*3-rgbCounter-3] = integer
                elif rgbCounter%3 == 1:
                    lineList[width*3-rgbCounter-1] = integer
                else:
                    lineList[width*3-rgbCounter+1] = integer
                rgbCounter += 1
                if rgbCounter == width*3:
                    outfile.write(' '.join(lineList))
                    outfile.write('\n')
                    rgbCounter = 0
    outfile.close()
```

And here's the problem:  When I run this code, the "print" line after `if i > 2:` also prints line 2 (or rather, line 3, the line indexed at 2)!  In a more minimal example, if I just say

```
...
if i > 2:
    print line
...
```

It will only print lines 4 and after, but something about the rest of the code that I'm actually running makes it print line 3.  Any ideas why and how to fix this?

Here's a sample input:

```
P3
4 4
255
49   49   49    100   100   100     0   200   0     0   0   0 
100  100  100   100   0     0       200 200   200   255 255 255
200  100  0     0     100   200     0   0     0     50  50  50
0    0    0     0     0     0       0   0     0     0   0   0
```

and when I run the code I get the printed lines

```
4 4

49   49   49    100   100   100     0   200   0     0   0   0 

100  100  100   100   0     0       200 200   200   255 255 255

...
```

The first line, containing "4 4" shouldn't be there.

Comment: "When I write the minimal example the strange behavior goes away" is a major part of the reason to write minimal examples in the first place. That gives you a perfect way to proceed: Add back in half the stuff you skipped. Did the problem come back? Then take half of it back out. If not, put half of the remaining stuff back in. And so on. Within about 2-3 iterations you've usually identified exactly where things go wrong.

Comment: Meanwhile, please provide some sample input, and the desired and actual output.

Comment: As a side note, you obviously know about `with` statements, since you're using one for `infile`. So why aren't you also using one for `outfile`? (Also, why are you reusing the name `outfile` to mean both the filename and the open file object? That kind of thing is guaranteed to lead to confusion while debugging.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing the value of `i` in the statement 
`[None for i in range(width*3)]`. `i` will be `width*3 - 1` when it encounters `if i > 2`, which then evaluates to `True`.
Simply changing the name of the variable (`[None for j in range(width*3)]`) will do the trick. Note that `i > 2` means the first line to be printed will be the fourth one (index 3). If you want the third one to print, you should use `if i > 1`. 
minimal example showing the behaviour:

```
def test():
    a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    for i, char in enumerate(a):
        if i==1:
            var = [None for i in range(4)]
        if i>2:
            print(i, char)
             test()
```

Comment: Or, `[None] * (width * 3)`!

Comment: Using `elif` instead of `if` here would also solve the problem, and the OP really should make _both_ changes (or all three).

Comment: Somehow I don't like that notation @minitech mentioned, just because you can run into problems when doing things like `a = [[1,2]]*3`, and then `a[0][0] = 2` changes every item. Doesn't apply here, of course, but I've developed an irrational fear of that notation ;)